# javac -cp src\x\y\z src]x\y\z\*.java works but javac -cp src\x\y\z src\x\y\z\MainClass.java fails

Tags: java, maven, javac

My java project has 4 modules in directory `project\src\x\y\z`. A compile with maven or with `javac -cp src\x\y\z  src\x\y\z\*.java`  works (i.e. completes with no errors) and the timestamps indicate the class files were recreated, but
`javac -cp src\x\y\z  src\x\y\z\MainClass.java` fails with unable to find symbol errors where symbol is one of the other class names.

Attempting to run MainClass after a successful compile fails with cannot find MainClass error. (`java -cp src\x\y\z  src\x\y\z\MainClass`)

Each module includes a `package x.y.z;` statement. If I move the java modules to another folder and remove the package statements compiles and execution are both successful.

What is going on and can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

If the classes are in the package `x.y.z` then the directory that should be on your classpath needs to be `src/`, not `src/x/y/z`. The directories `x/y/z` are part of the structure that Java expects when searching for `.class` files in the package `x.y.z` and you must always point to the *base* of any directory tree containing `.class` files (i.e. so that the sub-directory matches what is expected by the package declaration).

Additionally if you want to run a class, you must specify the **class name** not a file name (i.e. `x.y.z.MainClass` and not `x/y/z/MainClass.java`). In fact `java` itself (i.e. the runtime, not the compiler) **only** cares about `.java` files when you run [single-file programs](https://www.baeldung.com/java-single-file-source-code), which is just a convenience feature for very simple code).

So `java -cp src/ x.y.z.MainClass` should run your code after `javac src\x\y\z\*.java` (the `-cp` here is wrong and unnecessary).

Ideally you would never have class files under `src/` at all (since that's short for "source" and not "binary class files"):

Builds tend to put them under something like `build/out/`, `bin/` or similar, but that's not required:

- `javac -d bin/ -cp bin/ src/x/y/z/*.java`
- `javac -d bin/ -cp bin/ src/x/y/z/MainClass.java` (maybe, optional after changing `MainClass.java`)
- `java -cp bin/ x.y.z.MainClass`